# How can I stop a SwiftUI TextField from losing focus when binding within a ForEach loop?

Tags: swiftui

In a form, I'd like a user to be able to dynamically maintain a list of phone numbers, including adding/removing numbers as they wish.

I'm currently maintaining the list of numbers in a published array property of an ObservableObject class, such that when a new number is added to the array, the SwiftUI form will rebuild the list through its ForEach loop. (Each phone number is represented as a `PhoneDetails` struct, with properties for the number itself and the type of phone [work, cell, etc].)

Adding/removing works perfectly fine, but when I attempt to edit a phone number within a TextField, as soon as I type a character, the TextField loses focus.

My instinct is that, since the TextField is bound to the phoneNumber property of one of the array items, as soon as I modify it, the entire array within the class publishes the fact that it's been changed, hence SwiftUI dutifully rebuilds the ForEach loop, thus losing focus. This behavior is not ideal when trying to enter a new phone number!

*I've also tried looping over an array of the `PhoneDetails` objects directly, without using an ObservedObject class as an in-between repository, and the same behavior persists.*

Below is the minimum reproducible example code; as mentioned, adding/removing items works great, but attempting to type into any TextField immediately loses focus.

**Can someone please help point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?**

```
class PhoneDetailsStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allPhones: [PhoneDetails]
    
    init(phones: [PhoneDetails]) {
        allPhones = phones
    }
    
    func addNewPhoneNumber() {
        allPhones.append(PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "", phoneType: "cell"))
    }
    
    func deletePhoneNumber(at index: Int) {
        if allPhones.indices.contains(index) {
            allPhones.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}


struct PhoneDetails: Equatable, Hashable {
    var phoneNumber: String
    var phoneType: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userPhonesManager: PhoneDetailsStore = PhoneDetailsStore(
        phones: [
            PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "800–692–7753", phoneType: "cell"),
            PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "867-5309", phoneType: "home"),
            PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "1-900-649-2568", phoneType: "office")
        ]
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(userPhonesManager.allPhones, id: \.self) { phoneDetails in
                let index = userPhonesManager.allPhones.firstIndex(of: phoneDetails)!
                HStack {
                    Button(action: { userPhonesManager.deletePhoneNumber(at: index) }) {
                        Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    TextField("Phone", text: $userPhonesManager.allPhones[index].phoneNumber)
                }
            }
            Button(action: { userPhonesManager.addNewPhoneNumber() }) {
                Label {
                    Text("Add Phone Number")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                }
            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840311/textfield-in-swiftui-loses-focus-when-i-enter-a-character) that asks a similar question, but its accepted answer did not help solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
    ForEach(userPhonesManager.allPhones.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                userPhonesManager.deletePhoneNumber(at: index)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            TextField("Phone", text: $userPhonesManager.allPhones[index].phoneNumber)
        }
    }
```

EDIT-1:

Reviewing my comment and in light of renewed interest, here is a version without using `indices`.
It uses the `ForEach` with binding feature of SwiftUI 3 for ios 15+:

```
class PhoneDetailsStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allPhones: [PhoneDetails]
    
    init(phones: [PhoneDetails]) {
        allPhones = phones
    }
    
    func addNewPhoneNumber() {
        allPhones.append(PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "", phoneType: "cell"))
    }
    
    // -- here --
    func deletePhoneNumber(of phone: PhoneDetails) {
        allPhones.removeAll(where: { $0.id == phone.id })
    }
    
}

struct PhoneDetails: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID() // <--- here
    var phoneNumber: String
    var phoneType: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userPhonesManager: PhoneDetailsStore = PhoneDetailsStore(
        phones: [
            PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "800–692–7753", phoneType: "cell"),
            PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "867-5309", phoneType: "home"),
            PhoneDetails(phoneNumber: "1-900-649-2568", phoneType: "office")
        ]
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($userPhonesManager.allPhones) { $phone in  // <--- here
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        userPhonesManager.deletePhoneNumber(of: phone)  // <--- here
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    TextField("Phone", text: $phone.phoneNumber)  // <--- here
                }
            }
            Button(action: { userPhonesManager.addNewPhoneNumber() }) {
                Label {
                    Text("Add Phone Number")
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                }
            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution does indeed work, but per [another SO post's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61687192), using `.indices` within a `ForEach` is not recommended since it can cause out-of-range errors. Why is using `.indices` not causing crashes in my code?

Comment: I've seen claims that using indices when adding or removing elements is not "recommended", 
the argument being that the range changes. Well this is not my experience and the example shows 
that it works without crashing. As far as I know when SwiftUI recomputes the view 
it will get the new range of indices avoiding any crash. This is what I see in this example.
But then again I maybe wrong.

Comment: This saved my life! Do we know why does the OP's code cause that problem, or is it a bug? It's been bothering me for hours

Comment: updated my answer with a (more robust) approach that does not use `indices`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, had struggled with the same issue for few days and the .indices workers specially that i have an array of string which doesn’t conform to identifiable.

I think i know why the indices work and not the id: .self .. it kinda make sense, when you pass the .self which is the value itself, as soon as the value changes it loses focus because the new value is not matching the old .self value. Passing an index on the other hand doesn’t change when the text is updated

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35458150)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).